# Библиотека под unix для работы с изображениями

Tags: c++, изображения, unix

Подскажите пожалуйста либу под unix, которая позволит выполнять все функции с изображениям: обрезать, склеивать, переворачивать, и т.д.

Желательно уже скомпилированную и с описанным API.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/ например

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, Да спасибо видел. Но разобраться так и не смог. Может быть есть еще? Желательно по проще. Спасибо.

Comment: Если попроще, можно Pillow, но это для питона.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вопрос не по стандартам, но

1. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html
2. http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html - с чем в этом примере вы не смогли разобраться?
3. еще более высокоуровневая либа http://cimg.eu/
4. что значит "уже скомпилированную"? если у вас проблемы со сборкой библиотеки с нуля -  для убунты есть готовый пакет libmagick++-dev

Comment: Попробую http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html, спасибо.

Comment: gil выглядит заброшенным в 2000-х годах.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian, и простым :)

Comment: за CImg - плюс.

Comment: @MonahTuk оффтопом, про топленое масло - http://go.access.ru/guests/vred_ghee.html